Does canal only mean waterway? Can canal mean way in land?

we love our electric bikes. We love to go out on trails and canals.

Does canal only mean waterway? Can canal mean way in land?

Why do you think canals are a type of road? When the speaker says canals, they are referring to the paths that accompany them.

It is an unusual use of the preposition on mainly because of the compound objects.  The phrase would be edited by an editor. Better would be "... on trails and along canals".  "We love to take our bikes out on canals" would not make clear sense.

People riding electric bikes at 30mph on trails that say "no motorized vehicles"  have become very numerous and I wish that they would indeed ride them "on canals".

A canal (in the sense of "way") does just mean a man-made waterway. In this sentence "canals" refers to the towpaths that run alongside canals, a throwback to when canals were first built and the boats on them were horse-drawn.

On a nice Saturday my wife and I can go to Bath, a nearby town, and walk along the Kennet and Avon Canal a few miles, and we do not need to walk upon the water.

It's also common to walk along a river which doesn't require getting your feet wet. "On" and "along" can mean beside/adjacent to.
